# Switch between two windows in selenium webdriver

Tags: windows

I am getting error of `NoSuchWindowException` with this code.I am unable to switch back to old opened window and get back to new window
please review my code and help me.

```
public void TC_123617()throws InterruptedException      {
         driver.findElement(By.id("user_login")).sendKeys("akhil");
         driver.findElement(By.id("user_pass")).sendKeys("akhil");
         driver.findElement(By.id("wp-submit")).click();
         Thread.sleep(3000); 
         driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#awebsome_oruw-2 > ul")).click();
         WebElement userStatus = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='awebsome_oruw-2']/ul/li[11]"));
         String parentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();          
         driver = new FirefoxDriver();        
         driver .manage().window().maximize();        
         driver.get("http://103.16.143.96/incis/wp-login.php");
         driver.findElement(By.id("user_login")).sendKeys("manager");
         driver.findElement(By.id("user_pass")).sendKeys("manager");
         driver.findElement(By.id("wp-submit")).click();  
         for (String popUpHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
           if(!popUpHandle.equals(parentWindow)){
              driver.switchTo().window(popUpHandle);      
            driver.switchTo().window(parentWindow);  
           }
         }
    }
```

Comment: Are you creating new instance of Firefox Driver?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a new driver instance if you want to switch between windows using driver.
Save a reference to current window. (so that you can return to perform actions on the window you started from.)

`String parentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();`

Next Step, get all the windows and switch to the new window.

`List<String> allWindows = driver.getWindowHandles();
for(String curWindow : allWindows){
    driver.switchTo().window(curWindow);
}`

Now, you can perform any action on the new window, and when done you could close it using

`driver.close();`

Finally, you can switch back to the parent window to continue your actions using

`driver.switchTo().window(parentWindow)`